# Bigquery - Deleting/Updating a table parallelly from 2 different cron jobs results in failure

Tags: java, google-bigquery, cron

I have 2 java cron jobs which runs on different intervals to perform some operations and also delete and update a common big-query table.
There are some cases when both the jobs run at same time, try to delete/update the common table, resulting in failure of any one of the jobs.

Is there a concept like locking or some other way in big-query, so that once a job starts updating a table, the other job just wait for the operation to get completed.

Answer (score 0):

BQ doesn't have any locking feature, DML modifications generally fail if data is in changing state while the query is running. You'll have to implement these operations sequentially in your code  ie read -> write / write-> read or you can try implementing your requirement using [Cloud Composer](https://cloud.google.com/composer) using dags ie.reading from BQ --> writing to BQ.